# How easily can one single slap kill a person?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, death, fight

On the left side we have Emperor Kaht, 23 years old, 67.5 kilograms of weight with a height of 178 centimetres.

On the right side, the northern kingdom's hero, a man of which fame stomps that of Heracles. The only Lu Bearskin, 45 years old, 138 kilograms and 196 centimetres.

In response to the emperor's insult, Lu softly grabs his majesty by the shoulder and the proceeds to slap him with such might that his teeth fly out.  Then the emperor dies shortly after his eyes start bleeding from the inside.

Is the impact from a slap enough to cause internal bleeding in the head?

Comment: I've added a few relevant tags for your approval. Should we assume no pre-existing major medical conditions (or poisons, deliberate or not) in the Emperor? (There are certainly one or two which might make this more likely).

Comment: If my grandparents are to be believed, a hard enough slap('hard' being possible by normal people) to the temple is enough to kill anyone. Needless to say I've never actually researched or investigated this, so I can't provide that as an answer.

Comment: It could be very different because of what he slaps with (back of metal gauntlet), how he slaps (really more of a punch) and into what the emperor is slapped (marble pillar). Then you could crush a skull. Are we talking mid-air open-palm? Better chances to accidentally snap a neck. Is this supposed to be "accidental" death?

Comment: A 23-year-old might become an arrogant, insulting Emperor by killing a lot of older relatives, so hidden blades and ready poisons and treacherous cunning and villainous strength to resist powerful slaps seem plausible. Of course, treacherous cunning means the insult is unlikely, but perhaps he's distraught over the loss of all his goons.

Comment: the grabbing by the shoulder severely restricts the slappers freedom of movement. he can slap a lot harder starting from a distance.

Comment: The age of the person being slapped also is important. A young person whose skull has not fully fused could have a slap drive bones around. An older person being slapped could have concussion or brain bleeding from the impact.

Comment: *to slap him with such might that his teeth fly* This is beyond any normal use of the word "slap".  A blow this hard would have no practical difference to a really hard punch.  So your question really sounds more like "Can a single punch to the jaw kill a man".

Comment: Poor little emperor.. I wouldn't know an answer to your macabre question, but why provoke, and NOT prepare for the response ? If you're 23 and fighting a guy twice your weight, better be quick

Answer (score 7):

[It was indeed the slap that killed](https://bangaloremirror.indiatimes.com/bangalore/cover-story/it-was-indeed-the-slap-that-killed/articleshow/21195315.cms)

> While the neurogenic shock (resulting from damage to the central nervous system) was due to the impact of the slap, her collapse is attributed to non-function of the heart’s mitral valve...

[Father who killed his 13-year-old daughter with two slaps](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2636980/Father-killed-daughter-13-two-slaps-didnt-like-washed-floor-jailed-just-60-DAYS.html)

> ...13-year-old Noutene Sidime and slapped her on both sides of her face.
> The girl collapsed to the floor unconscious with blood trickling from her nose...
> The 13-year-old girl spent three days in a coma at the Montreal Children's Hospital before succumbing to her injures
> A medical examiner determined that the teenager died from a cerebral hemorrhage caused in part by the slaps.

[Slapping contests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slapping_(strike)#Slapping_contests).
*If you want an approximate depiction of the story in the question in a youtube video, [watch this for about 1 minute](https://youtu.be/s4mGOrbEKbs?t=480)*

> In Russian bodybuilding championships, slapping contests are often held between contestants... the fall of the reigning champion Vasily "Dumpling" Kamotsky, who was recently dethroned after being put into a "mini coma" by an unnamed opponent

[Man kills co-worker with slap in face](https://thecurrent.pk/man-kills-co-worker-with-slap-in-face/)

> A neurologist told Gulf News, “The face has a huge array of nerve endings, contains around 40 muscles and 14 bones and has sensitive skin, the cartilage of the nose, joint of the jaw and eyes. A hard slap cannot only damage any of these parts but also affect the blood flow from the heart to the brain.”

Comment: This could be a better answer if you typed up explanations for all this evidence.

Comment: @Firestryke taking it in order: neurogenic shock and mitral valve stopping, cerebral hemorrhage (likely following a concussion), affecting  blood flow from the heart to the brain (see also [vagal maneuver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vagal_maneuver)). Seems like an awful lot of causes for a limited space and available time.